# Replicate apple's mailComposer UITextView?

Tags: objective-c, email, ios4, uiimage, uitextview

I want to replicate apple's default mail composer for my app. I don't want to use default mailcomposer because I'm having a lot of other things. Does anybody have solution for this? Main thing I want to implement is attachments. Like when you select a image and tap on email on photos app. The image preview is displayed in body part and also we can enter text and the cursor also detects the image when you press return or back. That functionality I want to achieve.

Comment: This isn't even a question. It's more like a request for someone to provide an implementation for you. Maybe you should hire someone with real money.

Answer (score 0):

The TTMessageComposer in the Three20 library is a good start... it doesn't have attachment support but will save you time on the standard layout.

[Three20 library](http://three20.info/)

Comment: I need an alternate or any other approach with all fields like cc/bcc and attachments preview and handling like default mail composer.

Comment: As far as is understand Three20 is not under active development any more - one should use [Nimbus kit](http://nimbuskit.info/) now.

Comment: You should use whatever suits your needs, just because it isn't in active development does not immediately make it useless....

Answer (score 0):

Check out this source code https://github.com/thermogl/TITokenFieldView, it's a custom UI class for token fields but there is a exact replica of Apple's mail `UITextView`. Heres a snippet from the source. All you have to do is create an normal text view and add it to your view.

```
// Creating the text view
messageView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:yourView.contentView.bounds];

// Adding it as a subview
[yourView.contentView addSubview:messageView];

// Set the frame so it resizes with the view.
[messageView setFrame:yourView.contentView.bounds];
```

Comment: I have already used it and talked with the developer and he refused because he doesn't have time

Comment: Replicating apple's mail composer seems a quite tough job because no one has created this yet.

Comment: yeah true, the easiest thing would be just to implement the mail composer, but if you could try hacking it and looking at the project files, then you could be able to implement it in a separate view.